# how can I deal with the garbled string like '\xe7\xbe\x8e'?

Tags: python, string, unicode

I have a list of words like  `s = ['a','\xe7\xbe\x8e\xe7','b']`, and I want to remove the members like `'\xe7\xbe\x8e\xe7'`, but I cannot think of any useful method. I have never deal with such kind of encoded or decoded words. I wish any suggestion in python. Thanks!

Comment: Are you using `python 2.7.x`?

Comment: yes,I am using 2.7.14

Comment: For what it's worth, I thought E7 BE 8E looked vaguely like UTF-8, but it isn't.

Comment: @tripleee `\xe7\xbe\x8e` *is* UTF-8 for the common Chinese character `美`, but the trailing `\xe7` wouldn't be valid.

Comment: My bad. Perhaps worth exploring further then? Many beginners want to discard bad data when the proper solution is to figure out why it's bad, and fix the root cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def is_ascii(s):
    return all(ord(c) < 128 for c in s)
s=[e for e in s if is_ascii(e)]
```

Try this. It will remove entries with non-ascii characters (like `\xe7\xbe\x8e\xe7`). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can check if each word in a list is `alphanumeric` using [`isalnum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum)
function. If word is alphanumeric then keep it otherwise drop it. This can be achieved using list comprehension

```
>>> s = ['a','\xe7\xbe\x8e\xe7','b']
>>> [a for a in s if a.isalnum()]
>>> ['a', 'b']
```

**Note**: `isalnum` checks if string is alphanumeric i.e. contains letters and/or numbers. If you want to allow letters only then use [`isalpha`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha) instead

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import itertools

s = ['a','\xe7\xbe\x8e\xe7','b']
for i in range(s.count("\xe7\xbe\x8e\xe7")):
    s.remove('\xe7\xbe\x8e\xe7')
```

Then all occurences of "\xe7\xbe\x8e\xe7" will be removed from the list.

Comment: Wait, did you mean to remove all instances of non-ASCII characters?

Comment: sorry for my misleading expression

Comment: I think that is implied, but you can leave it here

Comment: Note: the title was edited because of this misunderstanding